# Can't train a keras model to approximate a simple function

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I just got started with machine learning and I tried to write a simple program where the nn will learn the simple function y = f(x) = 2x.

Here's the code:

```
#x is a 1D array of 1 to 1000
x = np.arange(1,1000, 1)
y = x*2

xtrain = x[:750]
ytrain = y[:750]
xtest = x[750:]
ytest = y[750:]

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
          optimizer='sgd', 
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, 
                batch_size=100, 
                epochs=20, 
                verbose=1, 
                validation_split=0.2)
```

I get the following output, no matter how I change the architecture or the hyperparameters:

```
79999/79999 [==============================] - 1s 13us/step - loss: 8533120007.8465 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 32532613324.8000 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

the accuracy is 0 all the time. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a regression problem, accuracy is only for classification problems.

Comment: due to `tanh` in the second dense layer you are building a classifier (which can not predict values > 1). Additionally, the loss and metric don't seem to fit

Comment: I've tried other activations with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually what you would expect if you blindly run and expect gradient descent methods to *learn* any function. The behaviour you observe stems from 2 reasons:

1. The derivative that SGD uses to update weights actually depends on the input. Take a very simple case `y = f(wx + b)`, the derivative of `y` with respect to `w` is `f'(wx + b)*x` using the chain rule. So when there is an update for an input that is extremely large / unnormalised it blows up. Now the update is basically `w' = w - alpha*gradient`, so the weight suddenly becomes very small, in fact negative.
2. After a single gradient update the output became negative because the SGD just overshot. Since you again have `relu` in the final layer, that just outputs 0 and the training stalls because when the output is negative derivative of `relu` is 0.

You can reduce the datasize to `np.arange(1, 10)` and reduce the number of hidden neurons to say 12 (more neurons make the output even more negative after single update as all their weights become negative as well) and you will be able to train the network.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works check this out. I used `randn` instead of `arange`. Other things are pretty much the same.

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = x*2

xtrain = x[0:750]
ytrain = y[0:750]


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
          optimizer=sgd, 
          metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
                batch_size=100, 
                epochs=20, 
                verbose=1, 
                validation_split=0.2)
```

If you want to use the earlier dataset(ie `arange`). Here is accompanying code for that.

```
x = np.arange(1,1000, 1)
y = x*2

xtrain = x[0:750]
ytrain = y[0:750]


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()
sgd = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
          optimizer=sgd, 
          metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
                batch_size=100, 
                epochs=200, 
                verbose=1, 
                validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: This is a completely different problem when you change the dataset.

Comment: OP wanted to show that the Model learns a y = f(x) = 2x. The dataset was chosen arbitrarily I think. Hence I feel my code does justice to what the OP wanted. I have updated the code to include both now.